# Upgrade to a Beta package not possible because referenced

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

I am trying to install a new Beta package of our app into a sandbox. The install fails and tells me that "Cannot upgrade to a managed-beta version" because " cannot be upgraded using a managed-beta version of this package because it is referenced by an extension package developed in this organization. Please install a managed-released version of this package to complete the upgrade."

But there is neither a package created from this sandbox nor an installed one that references the package i am trying to upgrade.

Any idea what else could cause the upgrade to fail?

Comment: Maybe if you try un-installing the beta package, it will tell you what packages are referencing it...might be worth a shot to get some insight as to what it thinks is locking it

Answer (score 1):

You can't "upgrade" a managed beta package.  The only way to go from one beta version to another is to uninstall the previous beta and install the new one.  This means that an "upgrade" of a beta requires you to remove all references in the org to the beta package.

If you go to Setup -> Installed Packages and try to uninstall the beta package, you should get a list of the references which prevent the package from uninstalling.

Comment: It is definitely possible to upgrade from a released version to a higher beta version. We did this already for other orgs and other packages. You just cannot upgrade from beta to released.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was thinking you were going from one beta version to another beta version.  However, I think the same approach would still work.  Try to uninstall the currently installed production package and it should tell you all the metadata which is referencing it and blocking the uninstall.